# My Laravel Routing doesnt work anymore, it shows 404

Tags: laravel, routes, http-status-code-404

I have an adminmodul, where I can edit or delete some user profiles and i can activate or deactivate an user profile.

Everything works perfect. But suddenly my routes doesnt work anymore. Now I got the error 404 - page not found.

I dont know what the problem is, because I dont change anything in the code.

I think my routes doesnt working. Does anyone know why?

I tried to change my routes.

```
<?php


Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index');

Route::get('/{id}',[
    'as' => 'adminmodul.deactivate',
    'uses' => 'AdminController@deactivate'
]);



Route::resource('/adminmodul', 'AdminController');

Route::get('/{id}/edit', 'AdminController@edit')->name('adminmodul.edit');
```

this is my web.php

i have a AdminController.php where I have methods: index, create(dont use this), edit, update, destroy and deactivate

for example:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);
        $angebot = Angebot::where('firma', $id);
        $angebot->delete();
        $user->delete();

        return redirect('/')->with('success', 'Nutzer wurde erfolgreich gelöscht');
    }


    public function deactivate($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);
        if ($user->verified == 1){
            $user->verified = 0;
            $user->save();
            $angebot = Angebot::where('firma', $id);
            $angebot->delete();
            return redirect('/')->with('success', 'Nutzer wurde erfolgreich deaktiviert');
        }

        if($user->verified == 0){
            $user->verified = 1;
            $user->save();
            return redirect('/')->with('success', 'Nutzer wurde erfolgreich aktiviert');
            }

    }
```

the index page is working. My views are located in resources/views/adminmodul and then, create.blade.php, edit.blade.php, show.blade.php and index.blade.php

if i hover over the Link, it shows me the right link /1/edit but if I click on this link it goes to /edit

i tried this:

```
public function test()
{

   return 'test';
}
```

Route::get('/test', 'AdminController@test');

but it doesnt work either and shows me 404

Why do I get 404 page not found?

Comment: Are other links working on your app? Did you create a simple route to a controller and checked?

Comment: yes i changed the post

Comment: Did that worked?

Comment: clear your router cache `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: If you are overriding most of the `Route::resource('/adminmodul', 'AdminController');` route, why are you still using it? Please run `php artisan route:list` and check the result... I think that there's a conflict between the `resource` routes and the rest

Comment: Try clearing the cache by following commands:
php artisan route:cache 
php artisan cache:clear 
php artisan config:cache
Still issue:
Check your htaccess and whether rewrite mode is enabled.
Check if simple route to controller works.

Answer (score 0):

Put your edit route above Route::resource

```
Route::get('/{id}/edit', 'AdminController@edit')->name('adminmodul.edit');
Route::resource('/adminmodul', 'AdminController');
```

Note that your new methods have to go above the Route::resource

Answer (score 0):

I think because of wildcards you should try this order to avoid conflict

```sh
Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index');

Route::get('/{id}/edit', 'AdminController@edit')->name('adminmodul.edit');

Route::get('/{id}',[
    'as' => 'adminmodul.deactivate',
    'uses' => 'AdminController@deactivate'
]);

Route::resource('/adminmodul', 'AdminController');
```